# Monitoring network connection type change in Android Service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to capture the network connection type change in Android Service and run a code of this Service when the event fires. How to do that inside a Service class only without separate class? I have this code, but it doesn't work.

```
 BroadcastReceiver networkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            playlist="NETWORK TYPE CHANGED";
        }
    };

 public void playSong(Context c, String url) {

        try
        {

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);        
            registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your BroadcastReceiver needs to receive the Intent from the system, so you need to register your BroadcastReceiver in your AndroidManifest

```
<receiver
    android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and do not forget the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: It's strange but it began working without it. As I see, it's a dynamic Receiver, not a separate class file. I tried to use your suggestion before, but there was a problem of passing data to and from Service. So I decided to do it in a Service class. Usually the name of Receiver is equal to a class file name, but here it's made on the fly.

Comment: so I guess you kept the permission, are you sure, your Receiver is still alive when the network connection change happens?

Comment: The permission was initially for other purposes already. I'm not sure.

Comment: As I see it your IntentFilter is registered locally in the playSong-Method, so once the Method is finished it will be garbaged, I would assume. Try declaring the filter in the Activity and only assigning in your playSong-Method

Comment: The problem's that Activity can be destroyed. But music must play, and receiver must monitor the connection change.

Comment: sounds logical. Then can you pass the data to and from the service by an Intent or even by a file that is stored? You can call the Receiver from within your activity as well and pass the information.

Comment: As I see it: all is stored inside a Service Class, and when network type changes, there is a stream stop, so there must be a call to restart() method. But this must be monitored only when MediaPlayer is playing.

Comment: Correct. The Service can start the activity when needed and take the events from the Broadcast Receiver

Comment: Well, I'll look further, how would work my current code. Maybe the receiver can be made on the fly with each method start... Thanks. Now the activity starts the Service.